# What are some Facebook contact integration alternatives?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, htc-hero, facebook

I'm using HTC Hero.

I really love its seamless integration with facebook contacts.
My favorite thing about this feature is that I can link my google contact to facebook contact then automatically get profile picture and birthday information from facebook.

since I can't get any decent froyo ROM for HTC Hero, I use [this](http://www.villainrom.co.uk/forum/content.php?230-FroydVillain-1.7.2-Released!) non-htc-sense ROM and now I miss that feature.

is there any application that (or any way to)  bring similar feature?

Comment: This is not Sense-specific.  It should work with the Android contacts app regardless.

Comment: @Matthew maybe I miss something. But with the new ROM, I can't figure out how to connect my contact to a facebook profile.

Comment: OK, added an answer with steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the Facebook app, go to settings -> Sync Contacts -> check either Sync all or Sync with existing contacts.  Then in the contacts app, go to Display options and find your Facebook account in the list, then check All contacts.  They should show up in your contact list then.  To join them with existing google contacts, go into one of the contacts, edit it, hit menu and select Join, then find the other contact and select it.

Comment: Bonus: If you have contacts that aren't linked (most probable cause: name differences), if you edit the contact and tap the menu icon, there's probably going to be a "Join" item that lets you manually select the Facebook contact.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Facebook account is set to sync contacts (Settings -> Accounts and sync -> Facebook -> Sync Contacts).  Then in the Contacts app, Select a contact -> Hit the Menu button -> Join contact -> Select the contact to merge.

Comment: thank you. but @maxpower47 answer is 4 minutes earlier. +1

Comment: My one complaint about touchscreen phones: Slow typing :P